# Using HTML in a string in XML Attribute

Tags: html, xml

I have the following XML Code and want to use HTML in the text-attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<formLayout xmlns="xxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="xxx">

        <extension id="form_description_notes" label="Description notes" text="HERE HTML"/>

</formLayout>
```

I could do it like that:

```
&lt;br /&gt; Use this link for further information: &lt;a href='http://www.google.de'&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;
```

But this is very uncomfortable.

Any ideas to this?

Answer (score 0):

Using character references like that is the only way to include special characters in attribute values in XML.

If you were using a child node instead of an attribute then you could use a CDATA block or just import elements from the XHTML namespace.

Comment: I am using this Java Code to return the text-attribute later.
`public String render(IPObject object, Map<String, String> attributes) {
     String text = attributes.get("text");
     
     
        return text;
    }`

Is there an possibility to get the data from a child node?